# Parsing XML Attributes PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm attempting to echo the *minutes* attribute under each *routeTitle*.

My output: http://zxstudios.ca/api/test2.php

XML: http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=predictions&a=ttc&stopId=1974

```
<?php

$stopid="1974";
$urlbase = "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=predictions&a=ttc&stopId=";
$url = $urlbase.$stopid;

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$rt = $xml->predictions;

foreach ($rt as $value) {
    echo $value->attributes()->routeTitle."Min. <br>";
}

echo $rt->direction->attributes()->minutes;

?>
```

So for example:

```
325-Don Mills
3 Min.
1 Min.
185-Don Mills Rocket
2 Min.
1 Min.
25-Don Mills
2 Min.
1 Min.
```

**Updated question:** how do I access the correct node and avoid "Warning: main(): Node no longer exists..." ?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Sorry* my questions is how do I access the correct node and avoid "Warning: main(): Node no longer exists..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to echo *minutes* attribute values for each *routeTitle*, then your `foreach` loop should be like this:

```
// your code

foreach ($rt as $value) {
    echo $value->attributes()->routeTitle . '<br />';
    if(isset($value->direction)){
        foreach($value->direction->prediction as $attr){
            foreach($attr->attributes() as $k => $v){
                if($k == 'minutes'){
                    echo $v . ' minutes <br />';
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "No direction. <br />";
    }
}
```